# Get Standard Deviation From Groups in Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame formatted as below:

```
user <- c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
answer_num <- c(1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6)
df <- data.frame(user,answer_num)
```

I am trying to collect stats about the number of instances of an answer, within each user. For instance I can get the mean number of instances of each answer with:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(user) %>% summarise(inst_per_answer = n()/length(unique(answer_num)))
```

which gives me:

```
  user inst_per_answer
1    1            1.0
2    2            2.0
3    3            1.5
```

How would I get the standard deviation of the number of instances of each answer?

**Clarification**:
I'm looking for the standard deviation of the number of instances of each answer. For example, user 1 has 1 instance of answer 1 and 1 instance of answer 2. Therefore, the standard deviation is 0 - `sd(c(1,1))`. User 3 has 2 instances of answer 5 and 1 instance of answer 6, for a sd of 0.7 - `sd(c(2,1))`.

Comment: there is no sd of a single number, but you could do `sd(answer_num)`

Comment: @RichardScriven oh is he wanting across groups? you should post it

Comment: That doesn't seem to be giving me the right answer

Comment: It doesn't. Can you clarify what you are taking the SD of?

Comment: Sure. I'll add some clarification

Comment: Why the `sd` for user 3 is `0.7`? How did you calculate this?

Comment: There are 2 instances of answer 5, and 1 instance of answer 6. The standard deviation of 1 and 2 is 0.7

Comment: Perhaps `apply(table(df), 1, function(x) sd(x[x!=0]))`

Comment: `aggregate(answer_num ~ user, data=df, FUN=function(x) sd(table(x))`

Comment: Or using `data.table` `setDT(df)[, list(inst_per_answer= .N/uniqueN(answer_num), SD=sd(table(answer_num))), user]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this maybe

```
df %>%
  group_by(user, answer_num) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  summarise(sd_per_user = sd(n))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
#   user sd_per_user
# 1    1   0.0000000
# 2    2   0.0000000
# 3    3   0.7071068
```

Or a shorter version

```
df %>%
  count(user, answer_num) %>%
  summarise(sd_per_user = sd(n))

# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
#   user sd_per_user
# 1    1   0.0000000
# 2    2   0.0000000
# 3    3   0.7071068
```

---

Or a `data.table` version (using @Thelas base R idea)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(sd_per_user = sd(table(answer_num))), by = user]
#    user sd_per_user
# 1:    1   0.0000000
# 2:    2   0.0000000
# 3:    3   0.7071068
```

Answer (score 1):

For those interested in `sqldf`, two options:

RSQLite `STDEV`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT user, STDEV(n) AS sd
      FROM (SELECT user, answer_num, count(answer_num) AS n 
      FROM df GROUP BY user,answer_num) 
      GROUP BY user")
```

RH2, `STDDEV` or `STDDEV_SAMP`:

```
library(RH2)
sqldf("SELECT user, STDDEV(n) AS sd
      FROM (SELECT user, answer_num, COUNT(answer_num) AS n 
            FROM df GROUP BY user,answer_num) 
      GROUP BY user")
```

Output:

```
  user        sd
1    1 0.0000000
2    2 0.0000000
3    3 0.7071068
```

Comment: `stdev` works with RSQLite and `stddev_samp` with RH2.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck I included the distinction. Thank you. I'm not completely sure if STDDEV and STDDEV_SAMP are interchangeable in H2 According to this web it seems so http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#stddev_samp

Comment: Yes, in H2 `STDDEV` is an alias for `STDDEV_SAMP`.  In fact, this: `sqldf("select stddev(demand) from BOD")` will use `STDDEV_SAMP` in the heading rather than `STDDEV` thus it seems `stddev` works with both sqlite and h2.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck Ok. Regarding the final part of your comment, I have tried `STDDEV` in this example without loading RH2 and it does not work. Should it work? Or maybe it is something not implemented in RSQLite.

Comment: There was an error in my comment. In the extension used by RSQLite there is only one d in `stdev` but in h2 there are two d's.  That is with SLQite:  `sqldf("select stdev(demand) from BOD")` .  and with H2:  `sqldf("select stddev(demand) from BOD")` .

Comment: @G. Grothendieck Thank you for the clarification